# Div element is not fixed

Tags: html, css, web

I am creating a basic `HTML` page and I have one main container div and it contains one header div that is fixed at the top and working fine. 
Next to the header, I have the `animation` div, and the images div, and next to the images I have one description div and I have divided the description div into two divs: `div1{float:left}` and `div2{float left}...` 
Now when I open the page and scroll down to reach div 1 and div2. I want that div2 should be fixed under the header when it reaches the header bottom... 
Is it possible to solve with simple `CSS` or `JS` or something else required?
If possible with `CSS` then how to proceed

Comment: Do you have any code snippets or jsfiddle link.

Comment: try using position:fixed, if not solved, try to post your sample code or link to any other external websites like Codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: please have a look https://jsfiddle.net/salathiapartap/w4n7dw2w/  WHen i scroll down, i want that my red div should move be fixed at top right bottom of the header and it should look like that it is fixed at the right side, only when i scroll down

Comment: You dont have any dis with class 'div1' or 'div2'?! Do you mean the weird float-menus div that are red and green?

Comment: That was just an example..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I see what you mean. You want the float-menus div to not go on top of the menu block (static-header div). Correct? In that case you just need it to be a higher z-index. Float-menus is currently z-index:201; so just make static-header a bigger number.

```
#static-header{
    z-index:301;
}
```

See my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z9bxhbfs/

Comment: Hi, No.. Its not like that. When it reaches to header bottom, it should stop over there and it should not go under and top of the header. That was I mean